# Using relational operators to find the score

Tags: java

So for the last part of my code, I'm trying to make a comment based on the number of questions the user got correct. If the user got 3 or more correct, I want to leave a congrats. But if the user got less than that, I want to leave a comment to study a bit more. I know I'm supposed to use relational operators to solve this but I'm kind of perplexed as to how I actually do it.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class quizcreation
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

   System.out.println ("If your answer is not one of the options, it will be considered incorrect.");
   System.out.println();

   //Question 1
   System.out.println ("T/F: Harry Potter was an only child.");
   String answer1 = input.next();

   if (answer1.equals("True"))
   {
      System.out.println("That is correct! Harry was an only child.");
      }   

   else if (answer1.equals("true"))
   {
      System.out.println("That is correct! Harry was an only child.");
      }
   else if (answer1.equals("TRUE"))
   {
      System.out.println("That is correct! Harry was an only child.");
      }
   else if (answer1.equals("t"))
   {
      System.out.println("That is correct! Harry was an only child.");
      }

   else if (answer1.equals("T"))
   {
      System.out.println("That is correct! Harry was an only child.");
      }

   else 
   {

      System.out.println("Sorry that is incorrect. Harry was an only child.");
    } 

   System.out.println();

   //Question 2
   System.out.println ("T/F: Ron Weasley has more than one brother.");
   String answer2 = input.next();

   if (answer2.equals("True"))
   {
      System.out.println(" 100% correct! Ron has 2 twin brothers.");
      }
   else if (answer2.equals("true"))
   {
      System.out.println("100% correct! Ron has 2 twin brothers.");
      }

   else if (answer2.equals("TRUE"))
   {
      System.out.println("100% correct! Ron has 2 twin brothers.");
      }
   else if (answer2.equals("t"))
   {
      System.out.println("100% correct! Ron has 2 twin brothers.");
      }
   else if (answer2.equals("T"))
   {
      System.out.println ("100% correct! Ron has 2 twin brothers.");
      }
   else 
   {
      System.out.println ("Sorry that is incorrect. Ron has 2 twin brothers.");
      }
   System.out.println();   

   //Question 3
   System.out.println("What was the first name of Harry's uncle?");
   System.out.println("a) Remus");
   System.out.println("b) Snape");
   System.out.println("c) Sirius");

   String answer3 = input.next();

   if (answer3.equals("a"))
   {
      System.out.println ("Sorry that is incorrect. ");
      }

   else if (answer3.equals ("A"))
   {
      System.out.println ("Sorry that is incorrect.");
      }

   else if (answer3.equals ("b"))
   {
      System.out.println ("Sorry that is incorrect. ");
      }

   else if (answer3.equals("B"))
   {
      System.out.println ("Sorry that is incorrect. ");
      }

   else if (answer3.equals ("C"))
   {
      System.out.println ("That is correct! ");
      }

   else if (answer3.equals ("c"))
   {
      System.out.println ("That is correct! ");
      }

   else 
   {
      System.out.println ("THAT WASN'T EVEN AN OPTION YO. This is incorrect.");
      }
   System.out.println();   

   //question 4

   System.out.println("What is the name of one of the houses at Hogwarts");
   String answer4 = input.next();

   if (answer4.equals("Gryffindor"))
   {
      System.out.println ("You are correct! Students from Gryffindor are known for their bravery.");
      }

   else if (answer4.equals("gryffindor"))
   {
      System.out.println("You are correct! Students from Gryffindor are known for their bravery.");
      }
   else if (answer4.equals("Slytherin"))
   {
      System.out.println( "You are correct! Slytherin are known for being cunning and ambitious.");
      }
   else if (answer4.equals("slytherin"))
   {
      System.out.println(" You are correct! Slytherins are known for being cunning and ambitious.");
      }
   else if (answer4.equals("Ravenclaw"))
   {
      System.out.println("You are correct! Ravenclaws are known for their intelligence.");
      }
   else if (answer4.equals("ravenclaw"))
   {
      System.out.println("You are correct! Ravenclaws are known for their intelligence.");
      }
   else if (answer4.equals ("Hufflepuff"))
   {
      System.out.println("You are correct! Hufflepuffs are known for their kindness.");
      }
   else if (answer4.equals ("hufflepuff"))
   {
      System.out.println("You are correct! Hufflepuffs are known for their kindess.");
      }
   else 
   {
      System.out.println(" Sorry that is incorrect :(");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of equals, and use `||` condition to make the code better.

Comment: Note also you should probably use `input.nextLine()` instead of `input.next()`, in order that you don't accidentally answer two questions at once (try entering `T T`) at the first question to see what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable at the top of your code, along the lines of

```
int correct = 0;
```

Then once it goes into one of your correct answers, update the variable by adding one to it, i.e. `correct++;`

Then at the bottom of the code, put in a new `if` statement.

```
if (correct >= 3) {
            //message here
        } else {
            //other message
        }
```

You can also drastically shorten the code by using `equalsIgnoreCase` and `||`  (or)

For example:

```
if (answer1.equalsIgnoreCase("True") || answer1.equalsIgnoreCase("T")) {
            System.out.println("That is correct! Harry was an only child.");
            correct++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry that is incorrect. Harry was an only child.");
        }
```

Comment: Another way of checking the answers is `Arrays.asList("TRUE", "T").contains(input.toUppercase())` - the nice thing about that being it is more amenable to creating a "Question" class, to shrink the code further.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you use `equalsIgnoreCase` method to compare `Strings` so that you avoid the ugly multiple `equals`. You can read more about it [in the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-).

Also, to determine the number of correct answers, use a simple `int` variable. For each correct response, increment it. At the end, make a decision based on the value of the final value of the counter.

This is the simplified version of your code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int correctAnswersCounter = 0;

System.out.println("If your answer is not one of the options, it will be considered incorrect.");
System.out.println();

//Question 1
System.out.println("T/F: Harry Potter was an only child.");
String answer1 = input.next();

// equalsIgnoreCase() works for all variations like 'true', 'TRUE', 'TrUe', 'truE' etc. for example

if (answer1.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || answer1.equalsIgnoreCase("t")) {
    System.out.println("That is correct! Harry was an only child.");
    correctAnswersCounter++;
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry that is incorrect. Harry was an only child.");
}

System.out.println();

//Question 2
System.out.println("T/F: Ron Weasley has more than one brother.");
String answer2 = input.next();

if (answer2.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || answer2.equalsIgnoreCase("t")) {
    System.out.println(" 100% correct! Ron has 2 twin brothers.");
    correctAnswersCounter++;
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry that is incorrect. Ron has 2 twin brothers.");
}
System.out.println();

//Question 3
System.out.println("What was the first name of Harry's uncle?");
System.out.println("a) Remus");
System.out.println("b) Snape");
System.out.println("c) Sirius");

String answer3 = input.next();

if (answer3.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
    System.out.println("Sorry that is incorrect. ");
} else if (answer3.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
    System.out.println("Sorry that is incorrect. ");
} else if (answer3.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
    System.out.println("That is correct! ");
    correctAnswersCounter++;
} else {
    System.out.println("THAT WASN'T EVEN AN OPTION YO. This is incorrect.");
}
System.out.println();

//question 4

System.out.println("What is the name of one of the houses at Hogwarts");
String answer4 = input.next();

if (answer4.equalsIgnoreCase("Gryffindor")) {
    System.out.println("You are correct! Students from Gryffindor are known for their bravery.");
    correctAnswersCounter++;
} else if (answer4.equalsIgnoreCase("Slytherin")) {
    System.out.println("You are correct! Slytherin are known for being cunning and ambitious.");
    correctAnswersCounter++;
} else if (answer4.equals("Ravenclaw")) {
    System.out.println("You are correct! Ravenclaws are known for their intelligence.");
    correctAnswersCounter++;
} else if (answer4.equals("Hufflepuff")) {
    System.out.println("You are correct! Hufflepuffs are known for their kindness.");
    correctAnswersCounter++;
} else {
    System.out.println(" Sorry that is incorrect :(");
}

// now make a decision based on the value of correctAnswersCounter
if(correctAnswersCounter > 3) {
    System.out.println("Congrats!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Try harder next time!");
}
```